# Is there an easy way to get an instance of PGconn from ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

I have some code which relies on `PGConn` to connect to my database.  However, I have an `ActiveRecord` connection already established.

Therefore, is there anyway I can get a `PGConn` from AR that I can use for the code in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the #raw_connection method of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`:

```
pgconn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
```

You can also fetch the connection particular to a model class from that class's `connection`:

```
pgconn = MyModelClass.connection.raw_connection
```

There's a pretty good [blog post](http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/216) by Daniel Azuma on the low-level connection API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I needed to use this to check why a heroku buildpack was not setting the database credentials as expected and used pgconn.host() etc... http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html